# Syntax error in SQL IF statement

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask

I'm using python Flask and can't get my head around why i'm getting error:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: IF SELECT count(*) FROM ProfilePicture WHERE userid =
```

Here is my code:

```
 > def updateProfilePicture(filename, image, userid):
    >     cursor = getCursor()
    >     binary = psycopg2.Binary(image)
    >     data = (userid, filename, binary, userid, filename, binary, userid)
    >     #SQL = """INSERT INTO ProfilePicture(id, image, userid)
    >      #                   VALUES    (%s, %s, %s)"""
    >     SQL = """IF SELECT count(*) FROM ProfilePicture WHERE userid = %s > 0 
    >     THEN
    >         UPDATE ProfilePicture SET id = %s, image = %s WHERE userid = %s
    >     ELSE
    >         INSERT INTO ProfilePicture(id, image, userid) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
    >     END IF"""
    >     print cursor.mogrify(SQL, data)
    >     cursor.execute(SQL, data)
    >     cursor.connection.commit()
    >     cursor.close()
    >     return
```

A simple insert works well but not the if statement.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think there is any such syntax in PostgreSQL

Comment: [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109061) looks like it might be related / applicable.

Comment: Better to use `if exists (select * from ...)`

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is what you want: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 0):

Since "ON CONFLICT" syntax is introduced in PostgreSQL 9.5, you have to test the existence of the row in python.

If you have a unique constraint on the userid you can use exceptions:

```
def updateProfilePicture(filename, image, userid):
    cursor = getCursor()
    binary = psycopg2.Binary(image)
    data = (userid, filename, binary, userid, filename, binary, userid)
    SQL = """INSERT INTO ProfilePicture(id, image, userid) VALUES    (%s, %s, %s)"""
    try:
        cursor.execute(SQL, data)
    except:
        cursor.rollback()
        SQL = """UPDATE ProfilePicture SET id = %s, image = %s WHERE userid = %s"""
        cursor.execute(SQL, data)
    cursor.connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not SQL syntax, it's the [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql.html) procedural language. It's primarily used to write [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html). You can use it for a one-off command, but you need to put it in a [`DO` block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html):

```
DO $$
BEGIN 
  IF (SELECT count(*) FROM ProfilePicture WHERE userid = %s) > 0 THEN
    UPDATE ProfilePicture SET id = %s, image = %s WHERE userid = %s;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO ProfilePicture(id, image, userid) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);
  END IF;
END
$$
```

Note, however, that your logic will not work if someone else is inserting into/deleting from `ProfilePicture` at the same time; you risk either losing the update, or inserting multiple records for the same `userid`. Avoiding this is [less than straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql).